# Use LINQ to denormailize a list of Objects

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, list

I'm going to use a customer/order scenario to demonstrate what I'm trying to accomplish in VB.NET (4.0).

I'm like to create the following "CustomerOrders" list using **LINQ**.

Consider the following three classes

```
Class Customer
    Public ID As Integer
    Public Name As String
    Public Property Orders As New List(Of Order)
End Class

Class Order
    Public ID As Integer
    Public CustID As Integer
    Public ItemID As Integer
    Public Qty As Integer
End Class

Class CusomerOrders
    Public Property CustID As Integer
    Public Property CustName As String
    Public Property OrderIJD As Integer
    Public Property ItemID As Integer
    Public Property Qty As Integer
End Class
```

**I want to create a new list of CusomerOrders, based on the total orders for the entire customer list. I can accomplish this using some nested loops. However, I'm wondering if this can be done in LINQ.**

```
Dim _Customers As New List(Of Customer)
_Customers.Add(New Customer With {.ID = 1, .Name = "John Smith"})
_Customers.Add(New Customer With {.ID = 2, .Name = "Mary White"})
_Customers.Add(New Customer With {.ID = 3, .Name = "Jane Doe"})

_Customers(0).Orders.Add(New Order With {.ID = 567, .CustID = 1, .ItemID = 12345, .Qty = 5})
_Customers(0).Orders.Add(New Order With {.ID = 821, .CustID = 1, .ItemID = 99233, .Qty = 17})
_Customers(0).Orders.Add(New Order With {.ID = 1024, .CustID = 1, .ItemID = 43819, .Qty = 3})

_Customers(1).Orders.Add(New Order With {.ID = 321, .CustID = 2, .ItemID = 34556, .Qty = 12})
_Customers(1).Orders.Add(New Order With {.ID = 901, .CustID = 2, .ItemID = 12345, .Qty = 22})
_Customers(1).Orders.Add(New Order With {.ID = 1530, .CustID = 2, .ItemID = 32145, .Qty = 9})

_Customers(2).Orders.Add(New Order With {.ID = 1214, .CustID = 3, .ItemID = 43556, .Qty = 2})
_Customers(2).Orders.Add(New Order With {.ID = 1239, .CustID = 3, .ItemID = 34560, .Qty = 51})

Dim _CustomerOrders As New List(Of CusomerOrders)

_Customers.ForEach(Sub(_Customer)
                       _Customer.Orders.ForEach(Sub(_Order)
                                                    _CustomerOrders.Add(New CusomerOrders With {.CustID = _Customer.ID,
                                                                                                .CustName = _Customer.Name,
                                                                                                .OrderIJD = _Order.ID,
                                                                                                .ItemID = _Order.ItemID,
                                                                                                .Qty = _Order.Qty})
                                                End Sub)
                   End Sub)
```

**Output**

```
CustID | CustName   | OrderID | ItemID | QTY
--------------------------------------------
1      | John Smith | 567     | 12345  | 5
1      | John Smith | 821     | 99233  | 17
1      | John Smith | 1024    | 43819  | 3
2      | Mary White | 321     | 34556  | 12
2      | Mary White | 901     | 12345  | 22
2      | Mary White | 1530    | 32145  | 9
3      | Jane Doe   | 1214    | 43556  | 2 
3      | Jane Doe   | 1239    | 34560  | 51
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `SelectMany` approach, which is done by using `From` on both collections and projecting the desired items as follows:

```
Dim query = From c In _Customers
            From o In c.Orders
            Where c.ID = o.CustID
            Select New CusomerOrders With
            {
                .CustID = c.ID,
                .CustName = c.Name,
                .OrderIJD = o.ID,
                .ItemID = o.ItemID,
                .Qty = o.Qty
            }
Dim _CustomerOrders = query.ToList()
```

I prefer a join to a `SelectMany` since it's quicker with local queries. The challenge with a join in this case is that you can't access `c.Orders` the way I've done above. If you had the orders in their own list it would've been possible and simpler to use a join.